# VBA code to search a column and sort it

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing a VBA code that has to find a specific column on sheet and sort it on specific citeria. This is my code

```
Sub SortExchangesEurope()

    Dim intCounter As Integer
    Dim rngExchange As Range
    intCounter = 1

    Do While Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, intCounter) <> ""
        If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, intCounter).Value = "Exchange" Then
            With Worksheets("Sheet1")
                Set rngExchange = .Range(.Cells(2, intCounter), .Cells(2, intCounter))
               MsgBox intCounter
             End With
        End If

        intCounter = intCounter + 1
    Loop

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("$A$2:$AP$778").AutoFilter Field:=intCounter, Criteria1:=Array( _
        "XBEL", "XBUD", "XBSE", "XQMH", "XWAR", _
        "BMEX", "XLIS", "XLIT", "XBUL", "ASEX", _
        "XDUB", "XBRU", "XLUX", "XSTO", "XSWX", _
        "XHEL", "XMOS", "MISX", "XCSE", "XVTX", _
        "IEPA", "XMIL", "XLIS", "BMEX", _
        "XLJU", "ASEX", "XRIS", "XBRA", "xlOn", _
        "XOSL", "XPAR", "XPRA", "XICE", "XIST", _
        "XTAL", "XMIL", "XTRN", "XBRU", "XLDN", _
        "XAMS", "XZAG", "XSWX", "XATH", "XMAD", "XOME", _
        "XMRV", "XADE", "XVTX", "XTAH", "RTSX", "XLTO", _
        "XDMI", "MFOX", "XMAD", "XMAT", "XTLX", "ICEU", _
        "XMON", "XTUR", "XBRD", "XEDX", "XOME", "XLIF"), Operator:=xlFilterValues

End Sub
```

The first part looks for the column that the name is in and the second part must sort only the field with the given codes in them. Both parts work fine separately,but they do not work together.

autofilter of range class failed  - I receive this error

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: So, you identify the column with "Exchange" and then you step the variable IntCounter by 1 before exiting the loop and proceeding to the Autofilter.  Are you sure you are filtering the right column?

Comment: When the code exits the if, intCounter has a value of 43 and that seems to be the problem, but I cant fix it

Comment: A quick workaround is to set the Field in your Autofilter to `RngExchange.Column`.  That will be the original column you searched for in your loop, prior to adding 1 to the counter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check and set the `AutoFilterMode` before using `AutoFilter`

```
Sub SortExchangesEurope()
    Dim wS As Worksheet
    Dim intCounter As Integer
    Dim rngExchange As Range

    Set wS = Sheets("Sheet1")
    intCounter = 1

    With wS
        Do While .Cells(2, intCounter).Value <> "Exchange" Then
           intCounter = intCounter + 1
        Loop
        Set rngExchange = .Range(.Cells(2, intCounter), .Cells(2, intCounter))

        '.Activate
        '.Range("B2").Activate
        If Not .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = True

        .Range("$A$2:$AP$778").AutoFilter Field:=intCounter, Criteria1:=Array( _
            "XBEL", "XBUD", "XBSE", "XQMH", "XWAR", _
            "BMEX", "XLIS", "XLIT", "XBUL", "ASEX", _
            "XDUB", "XBRU", "XLUX", "XSTO", "XSWX", _
            "XHEL", "XMOS", "MISX", "XCSE", "XVTX", _
            "IEPA", "XMIL", "XLIS", "BMEX", _
            "XLJU", "ASEX", "XRIS", "XBRA", "xlOn", _
            "XOSL", "XPAR", "XPRA", "XICE", "XIST", _
            "XTAL", "XMIL", "XTRN", "XBRU", "XLDN", _
            "XAMS", "XZAG", "XSWX", "XATH", "XMAD", "XOME", _
            "XMRV", "XADE", "XVTX", "XTAH", "RTSX", "XLTO", _
            "XDMI", "MFOX", "XMAD", "XMAT", "XTLX", "ICEU", _
            "XMON", "XTUR", "XBRD", "XEDX", "XOME", "XLIF"), Operator:=xlFilterValues

    End With 'wS

End Sub
```

Comment: When the code exits the if, intCounter has a value of 43 and that seems to be the problem, but I cant fix it